# I would like to archive my app, but I'm encountering the following error message in Xcode: "Module 'cloud_firestore' not found" Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, xcode, dart, google-cloud-firestore, podfile

I want to release my app on the App Store, but I'm encountering this error message. I'm using an M1 processor, in case that information is relevant.

This is my Podfile:

```
Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

and i use the version  cloud_firestore: ^4.8.2 & firebase_core: ^2.14.0.

Comment: Even when I create a new Flutter project and only add Firebase and Firestore packages, I still encounter this error message

Comment: Have you cross check with pod install command that all pods installed correctly ?

Comment: Yes, I have done that :/

Comment: Try to delete pods folder 
then
do following 
flutter clean,flutter pub get and
Open simulator from android studio
and do flutter run

Comment: I also have already done that

Comment: Is there any possibility to code share?